# Adding attribute to all query objects using annotate?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, orm

Is there a way I could add an attribute to all query objects using annotate? I basically just need to get a value from an m2m relationship of the object and save it as an attribute of the object.

Something like this: 
`query.annotate(value_to_be_added=("value_from_m2m"))`

Basically I have two different queries of the same model, one query A needs to have a "value" changed or added for all of its objects (and that value comes from the m2m relationship). Query B doesn't need to have those values changed.

How would I do this?

Comment: Not quite sure whetehr I fully understood what you are trying to achive. Have you considered using der F() [expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for your annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. What needs to be used is just a simple filter F().

`from django.db.models import F
query.annotate(value_to_be_added=F("value_from_m2m"))`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions